# How do I copy a row of data to a new sheet with a different number of columns?

Tags: google-apps-script

I know how to copy data from one sheet to another. 
I'm currently trying to do it for a new work project and I'm stumped.

I keep getting an error of 'The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet'

The same columns exist between all 4 sheets that I'm working with, BUT some are hidden. 
Is this why I am getting the message? That's the only thing I can think of. If so, how do I get around that?

Code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var RequestSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Request');
  var InProgressSheet = ss.getSheetByName('In Progress');
  var ReviewSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Ready for Review');
  var CompletedSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Completed');
  var HoldSheet = ss.getSheetByName('On Hold');

  var status = RequestSheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
  var row = RequestSheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var column = RequestSheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();

  var a1notation = ("A" + row + ":" + "X" + row);
  var newRange = RequestSheet.getRange(a1notation);

  if(status == 'In Progress') {
     newRange.copyTo(InProgressSheet.getRange(InProgressSheet.getLastRow() 
 + 1, 1))
  } else if (status == 'On Hold') {
      Browser.msgBox('On Hold was selected')
  } else if (status == 'Completed') {
      Browser.msgBox('Completed was selected')
  } else
      return
}
```

Comment: Try adding rows or columns to your sheet.  Share your code.

Comment: @Cooper what do you mean by adding columns to my sheet? As in add extra to see if it changes anything?

Comment: The error is saying that your trying to write outside of the dimensions of the sheet.  So I'm just saying make the dimension larger.  Or show me your code.

Comment: @Cooper code added. Tried adding 5 columns and got the same error.

Comment: I would guess that from this `newRange.copyTo(InProgressSheet.getRange(InProgressSheet.getLastRow() 
 + 1, 1))` that InProgressSheet.getLastRow() is in fact the last row in the sheet which means your target range is outside of the range of the target sheet.

Comment: So you need to add more rows

Comment: I had a hunch on something and it turned out to be correct.
The other sheets have a bunch of columns that have cells of list items to select.
So the getLastRow() was out of bounds because technically (even though nothing is selected) their is still data in those cells.

Comment: Sounds like you found the problem.

Comment: Hi @Michael , did what you mentioned in your previous comment solve your issue? If so, could you please formalise it in an answer so that everyone reaching this question can easily see what worked? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me.
The sheets that I was copying data to had certain cells with list items built-in to them. Shown here:

[image: screen shot for clarification]

So when

```
newRange.copyTo(InProgressSheet.getRange(InProgressSheet.getLastRow() 
 + 1, 1))
```

was called, getLastRow() + 1, 1 was out of bounds because all of the rows technically had data in them. I cleared all of those out and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var RequestSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Request');
  var InProgressSheet = ss.getSheetByName('In Progress');
  var ipslr=InProgressSheet.getLastRow();//modified
  var ReviewSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Ready for Review');

  var CompletedSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Completed');
  var HoldSheet = ss.getSheetByName('On Hold');

  var status = RequestSheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
  var row = RequestSheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var column = RequestSheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var newRange = RequestSheet.getRange(row,1,1,24);//modified
  if(ipslr==InProgressSheet.getMaxRows()) {
    InProgressSheet.insertRowsAfter(ipslr,100);//modified
  }
  if(status == 'In Progress') {
     newRange.copyTo(InProgressSheet.getRange(InProgressSheet.getLastRow() 
 + 1, 1))
  } else if (status == 'On Hold') {
      Browser.msgBox('On Hold was selected')
  } else if (status == 'Completed') {
      Browser.msgBox('Completed was selected')
  } else {
     return
  }
}
```